# bash sort array trouble

Tags: arrays, bash, ifs

My first sort statement works great but for some reason my second sort statement doesn't work and doesn't throw any errors. I can't spot the trouble. Please suggest ways I can make this script better. I know its really messy.

```
#!/bin/bash


testarr0=(37 32 11 31 41 10) 
#target ticket
testarr1=[];
#sort target ticket array


IFS=$'\n' testarr00=($(sort <<<"${testarr0[*]}"))
unset IFS


cou0=0
input="test_tickets0"
while IFS= read -r ticket0
do
IFS=',' read -ra digit0 <<< "$ticket0"
for i in "${digit0[@]}"; do
remv0="${i//]}"
remv1="${remv0//[}"


if [ $cou0 -eq 6 ];then
cou0=0
#sort array
IFS=$'\n' testarr11=($(sort <<<"${testarr1[*]}"))
unset IFS
#compare arrays
echo "${testarr00[@]}"
echo "${testarr11[@]}"
if [[ "[]${testarr00[@]}" == "${testarr11[@]}" ]];then
echo "match"
fi
testarr1=[]
fi
cou0=$((cou0+1))

if [ $cou0 -lt 7 ];then  
#push into array  
testarr1+=$remv1

fi

done
done < "$input"
```

Comment: Indenting your script goes a long way to improve readability. What are you trying to do with `[]`? And what's up with `"[]${testarr00[@]}"`? Paste your script at https://www.shellcheck.net and go over all the messages.

Comment: You noticed the messy stuff  right away I'm trying to reset testarr1 with [ ] and "[]${testarr00[@]}" is done because when i try to reset the array it appends [ ] to the front of the array when i echo it. This script is a big mess. Thanks for your time helping me straightening it out.

Comment: to push into the array, you need parentheses: `testarr1+=("$remv1")`

Comment: It would also help to show the contents of that file.

Comment: this is the contents of test_tickets0 file[32, 44, 10, 51, 22, 3]
[37, 32, 11, 31, 41, 10]
[31, 47, 16, 63, 14, 12]
[54, 32, 26, 51, 1, 7]
[56, 55, 30, 54, 25, 14]
[9, 46, 58, 20, 11, 19]
[12, 13, 39, 50, 67, 11]

Comment: I've straightened the script out some my main problem now is IFS won't sort testarr1